# LSTM: TensorFlow: Dst tensor is not initialized

Tags: python, tensorflow

I got this error while training my LSTM on data of shape: `(2044352, 140)`

Here's my code:

```
scaled_data = np.concatenate([scaled_price, scaled_features], axis=1)

n_epochs = 10
n_batch_size = 8 # smaller batch = slower training but better generalization
look_back = 10
X, y = create_dataset(scaled_data, look_back)
k = 3  # number of folds
random_seed = 13  # set the random seed value
kf = KFold(n_splits=k, shuffle=True, random_state=random_seed)

train_scores = []  # list to store train scores for each fold
test_scores = []   # list to store test scores for each fold

for i, (train_index, test_index) in enumerate(kf.split(X)):
    print("\n")
    print(f"Fold {i + 1} of {kf.get_n_splits()}")
    print("\n")

    X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
    y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]

    # model = Sequential()
    # # model.add(LSTM(100, input_shape=(X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2])))
    # model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(100, activation='relu'), input_shape=(X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2])))
    # model.add(Dropout(0.2))  # Add dropout with a dropout rate of 0.2 (adjust as needed)
    # model.add(Dense(1))
    # model.compile(optimizer=Adam(), loss='mean_squared_error')
    # model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=n_epochs, batch_size=n_batch_size, verbose=1)

    model = Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(250, input_shape=(X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2]), return_sequences=True)) # return_sequences=True if stacking layers
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))  # Add dropout with a dropout rate of 0.2 (adjust as needed)
    model.add(LSTM(100)
              # ,input_shape=(X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2])
             )
    model.add(Dense(1))
    model.compile(optimizer=Adam(), loss='mean_squared_error')
    model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=n_epochs, batch_size=n_batch_size, verbose=1)

    train_predict = model.predict(X_train)
    test_predict = model.predict(X_test)
    train_predict = scaler_price.inverse_transform(train_predict)
    test_predict = scaler_price.inverse_transform(test_predict)
    train_score = math.sqrt(mean_squared_error(y_train, train_predict))
    test_score = math.sqrt(mean_squared_error(y_test, test_predict))
    train_scores.append(train_score)
    test_scores.append(test_score)

# calculate average scores across folds
avg_train_score = np.mean(train_scores)
avg_test_score = np.mean(test_scores)

print(f'Average Train Score: {avg_train_score:.2f} RMSE')
print(f'Average Test Score: {avg_test_score:.2f} RMSE')
```

Here is my error message:

```
2023-12-19 11:40:36.750771: W tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:485] Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 3.55GiB (rounded to 3816103424)requested by op _EagerConst
If the cause is memory fragmentation maybe the environment variable 'TF_GPU_ALLOCATOR=cuda_malloc_async' will improve the situation. 
Current allocation summary follows.
Current allocation summary follows.
2023-12-19 11:40:36.750819: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1039] BFCAllocator dump for GPU_0_bfc
2023-12-19 11:40:36.750828: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1046] Bin (256):    Total Chunks: 47, Chunks in use: 46. 11.8KiB allocated for chunks. 11.5KiB in use in bin. 228B client-requested in use in bin.
2023-12-19 11:40:36.750834: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1046] Bin (512):    Total Chunks: 3, Chunks in use: 3. 1.8KiB allocated for chunks. 1.8KiB in use in bin. 1.2KiB client-requested in use in bin.
2023-12-19 11:40:36.750839: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1046] Bin (1024):   Total Chunks: 8, Chunks in use: 7. 12.8KiB allocated for chunks. 11.2KiB in use in bin. 9.8KiB client-requested in use in bin.
2023-12-19 11:40:36.750845: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1046] Bin (2048):   Total Chunks: 4, Chunks in use: 4. 8.8KiB allocated for chunks. 8.8KiB in use in bin. 6.2KiB client-requested in use in bin.
2023-12-19 11:40:36.750850: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1046] Bin (4096):   Total Chunks: 6, Chunks in use: 6. 29.8KiB allocated for chunks. 29.8KiB in use in bin. 23.4KiB client-requested in use in bin.
2023-12-19 11:40:36.750856: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1046] Bin (8192):   Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2023-12-19 11:40:36.750861: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1046] Bin (16384):  Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2023-12-19 11:40:36.750866: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1046] Bin (32768):  Total Chunks: 2, Chunks in use: 0. 96.0KiB allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2023-12-19 11:40:36.750872: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1046] Bin (65536):  Total Chunks: 3, Chunks in use: 2. 272.5KiB allocated for chunks. 187.5KiB in use in bin. 187.5KiB client-requested in use in bin.
2023-12-19 11:40:36.750877: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1046] Bin (131072):     Total Chunks: 11, Chunks in use: 9. 1.97MiB allocated for chunks. 1.61MiB in use in bin. 1.50MiB client-requested in use in bin.
2023-12-19 11:40:36.750882: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1046] Bin (262144):     Total Chunks: 3, Chunks in use: 3. 1.20MiB allocated for chunks. 1.20MiB in use in bin. 1.14MiB client-requested in use in bin.
2023-12-19 11:40:36.750887: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1046] Bin (524288):     Total Chunks: 7, Chunks in use: 7. 5.00MiB allocated for chunks. 5.00MiB in use in bin. 5.00MiB client-requested in use in bin.
2023-12-19 11:40:36.750892: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1046] Bin (1048576):    Total Chunks: 1, Chunks in use: 1. 1.13MiB allocated for chunks. 1.13MiB in use in bin. 976.6KiB client-requested in use in bin.
2023-12-19 11:40:36.750897: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1046] Bin (2097152):    Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2023-12-19 11:40:36.750902: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1046] Bin (4194304):    Total Chunks: 1, Chunks in use: 1. 6.73MiB allocated for chunks. 6.73MiB in use in bin. 5.20MiB client-requested in use in bin.
2023-12-19 11:40:36.750907: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1046] Bin (8388608):    Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2023-12-19 11:40:36.750911: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1046] Bin (16777216):   Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2023-12-19 11:40:36.750916: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1046] Bin (33554432):   Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2023-12-19 11:40:36.750920: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1046] Bin (67108864):   Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2023-12-19 11:40:36.750925: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1046] Bin (134217728):  Total Chunks: 1, Chunks in use: 0. 229.39MiB allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2023-12-19 11:40:36.750932: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1046] Bin (268435456):  Total Chunks: 6, Chunks in use: 2. 19.87GiB allocated for chunks. 14.22GiB in use in bin. 14.22GiB client-requested in use in bin.
2023-12-19 11:40:36.750938: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1062] Bin for 3.55GiB was 256.00MiB, Chunk State: 
2023-12-19 11:40:36.750949: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1068]   Size: 668.92MiB | Requested Size: 8B | in_use: 0 | bin_num: 20, prev:   Size: 256B | Requested Size: 4B | in_use: 1 | bin_num: -1
2023-12-19 11:40:36.750955: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1068]   Size: 1022.49MiB | Requested Size: 4B | in_use: 0 | bin_num: 20, prev:   Size: 7.11GiB | Requested Size: 7.11GiB | in_use: 1 | bin_num: -1
2023-12-19 11:40:36.750960: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1068]   Size: 1.05GiB | Requested Size: 4B | in_use: 0 | bin_num: 20, prev:   Size: 256B | Requested Size: 4B | in_use: 1 | bin_num: -1
2023-12-19 11:40:36.750965: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1068]   Size: 2.95GiB | Requested Size: 1.47GiB | in_use: 0 | bin_num: 20, next:   Size: 256B | Requested Size: 4B | in_use: 1 | bin_num: -1
2023-12-19 11:40:36.750969: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1075] Next region of size 8704360448
2023-12-19 11:40:36.750976: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1095] InUse at 7f988c000000 of size 7632206592 next 70
2023-12-19 11:40:36.750980: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1095] Free  at 7f9a52ea3b00 of size 1072153856 next 18446744073709551615
2023-12-19 11:40:36.750984: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1075] Next region of size 8589934592
2023-12-19 11:40:36.750988: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1095] InUse at 7fb3d4000000 of size 7632816896 next 474
2023-12-19 11:40:36.750992: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1095] InUse at 7fb59af38b00 of size 256 next 431
2023-12-19 11:40:36.750996: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1095] InUse at 7fb59af38c00 of size 256 next 590
2023-12-19 11:40:36.751000: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1095] InUse at 7fb59af38d00 of size 256 next 481
2023-12-19 11:40:36.751003: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1095] InUse at 7fb59af38e00 of size 256 next 626
2023-12-19 11:40:36.751007: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1095] InUse at 7fb59af38f00 of size 2048 next 196
2023-12-19 11:40:36.751011: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1095] InUse at 7fb59af39700 of size 1280 next 203
2023-12-19 11:40:36.751015: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1095] InUse at 7fb59af39c00 of size 2048 next 459
2023-12-19 11:40:36.751019: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1095] InUse at 7fb59af3a400 of size 4096 next 425
2023-12-19 11:40:36.751023: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1095] InUse at 7fb59af3b400 of size 2048 next 595
2023-12-19 11:40:36.751026: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1095] InUse at 7fb59af3bc00 of size 4096 next 325
2023-12-19 11:40:36.751030: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1095] InUse at 7fb59af3cc00 of size 256 next 41188
2023-12-19 11:40:36.751033: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1095] InUse at 7fb59af3cd00 of size 256 next 354
2023-12-19 11:40:36.751037: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1095] InUse at 7fb59af3ce00 of size 256 next 226
2023-12-19 11:40:36.751041: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1095] InUse at 7fb59af3cf00 of size 256 next 324
2023-12-19 11:40:36.751045: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1095] InUse at 7fb59af3d000 of size 400128 next 86
2023-12-19 11:40:36.751048: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1095] InUse at 7fb59af9eb00 of size 400128 next 268
2023-12-19 11:40:36.751052: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1095] InUse at 7fb59b000600 of size 7060224 next 97
2023-12-19 11:40:36.751059: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1095] InUse at 7fb59b6bc100 of size 560128 next 75
2023-12-19 11:40:36.751063: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1095] InUse at 7fb59b744d00 of size 560128 next 261
2023-12-19 11:40:36.751066: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1095] InUse at 7fb59b7cd900 of size 250112 next 405
2023-12-19 11:40:36.751070: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1095] InUse at 7fb59b80aa00 of size 1190144 next 350
2023-12-19 11:40:36.751074: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1095] InUse at 7fb59b92d300 of size 1000192 next 154
2023-12-19 11:40:36.751078: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1095] InUse at 7fb59ba21600 of size 560128 next 380
2023-12-19 11:40:36.751082: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1095] InUse at 7fb59baaa200 of size 560128 next 586
2023-12-19 11:40:36.751085: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1095] InUse at 7fb59bb32e00 of size 1000192 next 287
2023-12-19 11:40:36.751089: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1095] InUse at 7fb59bc27100 of size 1000192 next 460
2023-12-19 11:40:36.751093: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1095] Free  at 7fb59bd1b400 of size 240536832 next 352
2023-12-19 11:40:36.751096: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1095] InUse at 7fb5aa280100 of size 224000 next 278
2023-12-19 11:40:36.751100: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1095] Free  at 7fb5aa2b6c00 of size 87040 next 291
2023-12-19 11:40:36.751104: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1095] InUse at 7fb5aa2cc000 of size 256 next 20572
2023-12-19 11:40:36.751107: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1095] InUse at 7fb5aa2cc100 of size 256 next 125
2023-12-19 11:40:36.751111: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1095] InUse at 7fb5aa2cc200 of size 256 next 578
2023-12-19 11:40:36.751115: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1095] InUse at 7fb5aa2cc300 of size 1792 next 44
2023-12-19 11:40:36.751119: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1095] Free  at 7fb5aa2cca00 of size 256 next 20536
2023-12-19 11:40:36.751122: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1095] InUse at 7fb5aa2ccb00 of size 256 next 611
2023-12-19 11:40:36.751126: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1095] Free  at 7fb5aa2ccc00 of size 1536 next 334
2023-12-19 11:40:36.751130: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1095] InUse at 7fb5aa2cd200 of size 1792 next 92
2023-12-19 11:40:36.751133: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1095] InUse at 7fb5aa2cd900 of size 256 next 428
2023-12-19 11:40:36.751137: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1095] Free  at 7fb5aa2cda00 of size 48384 next 310
2023-12-19 11:40:36.751141: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1095] InUse at 7fb5aa2d9700 of size 256 next 362
2023-12-19 11:40:36.751144: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1095] Free  at 7fb5aa2d9800 of size 236800 next 580
2023-12-19 11:40:36.751148: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1095] InUse at 7fb5aa313500 of size 256 next 338
2023-12-19 11:40:36.751152: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1095] InUse at 7fb5aa313600 of size 256 next 207
2023-12-19 11:40:36.751155: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1095] Free  at 7fb5aa313700 of size 701417728 next 18446744073709551615
2023-12-19 11:40:36.751159: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1075] Next region of size 4294967296
2023-12-19 11:40:36.751163: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1095] Free  at 7fb74e000000 of size 3167582976 next 4994
2023-12-19 11:40:36.751166: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1095] InUse at 7fb80acd7b00 of size 256 next 237
2023-12-19 11:40:36.751170: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1095] InUse at 7fb80acd7c00 of size 256 next 274
2023-12-19 11:40:36.751174: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1095] Free  at 7fb80acd7d00 of size 1127383808 next 18446744073709551615
2023-12-19 11:40:36.751177: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1075] Next region of size 2097152
2023-12-19 11:40:36.751181: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1095] InUse at 7fbf3a000000 of size 256 next 1
2023-12-19 11:40:36.751185: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1095] InUse at 7fbf3a000100 of size 1280 next 2
2023-12-19 11:40:36.751189: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1095] InUse at 7fbf3a000600 of size 256 next 3
2023-12-19 11:40:36.751192: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1095] InUse at 7fbf3a000700 of size 256 next 4
2023-12-19 11:40:36.751196: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1095] InUse at 7fbf3a000800 of size 256 next 6
2023-12-19 11:40:36.751199: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1095] InUse at 7fbf3a000900 of size 256 next 7
2023-12-19 11:40:36.751203: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1095] InUse at 7fbf3a000a00 of size 256 next 8
2023-12-19 11:40:36.751207: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1095] InUse at 7fbf3a000b00 of size 256 next 13
2023-12-19 11:40:36.751210: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1095] InUse at 7fbf3a000c00 of size 256 next 5
2023-12-19 11:40:36.751214: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1095] InUse at 7fbf3a000d00 of size 256 next 11
2023-12-19 11:40:36.751217: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1095] InUse at 7fbf3a000e00 of size 256 next 18
2023-12-19 11:40:36.751221: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1095] InUse at 7fbf3a000f00 of size 256 next 17
2023-12-19 11:40:36.751225: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1095] InUse at 7fbf3a001000 of size 2816 next 16
2023-12-19 11:40:36.751229: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1095] InUse at 7fbf3a001b00 of size 256 next 20
2023-12-19 11:40:36.751232: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1095] InUse at 7fbf3a001c00 of size 256 next 25
2023-12-19 11:40:36.751236: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1095] InUse at 7fbf3a001d00 of size 256 next 26
2023-12-19 11:40:36.751239: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1095] InUse at 7fbf3a001e00 of size 256 next 27
2023-12-19 11:40:36.751243: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1095] InUse at 7fbf3a001f00 of size 224000 next 229
2023-12-19 11:40:36.751247: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1095] InUse at 7fbf3a038a00 of size 160000 next 372
2023-12-19 11:40:36.751253: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1095] InUse at 7fbf3a05fb00 of size 256 next 214
2023-12-19 11:40:36.751257: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1095] InUse at 7fbf3a05fc00 of size 4096 next 216
2023-12-19 11:40:36.751260: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1095] Free  at 7fbf3a060c00 of size 49920 next 20341
2023-12-19 11:40:36.751264: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1095] InUse at 7fbf3a06cf
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InternalError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[136], line 175
    172 model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=n_epochs, batch_size=n_batch_size, verbose=1)
    174 train_predict = model.predict(X_train)
--> 175 test_predict = model.predict(X_test)
    176 train_predict = scaler_price.inverse_transform(train_predict)
    177 test_predict = scaler_price.inverse_transform(test_predict)

File /opt/tensorflow/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py:70, in filter_traceback.<locals>.error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     67     filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
     68     # To get the full stack trace, call:
     69     # `tf.debugging.disable_traceback_filtering()`
---> 70     raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     71 finally:
     72     del filtered_tb

File /opt/tensorflow/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py:98, in convert_to_eager_tensor(value, ctx, dtype)
     96     dtype = dtypes.as_dtype(dtype).as_datatype_enum
     97 ctx.ensure_initialized()
---> 98 return ops.EagerTensor(value, ctx.device_name, dtype)

InternalError: Failed copying input tensor from /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 to /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 in order to run _EagerConst: Dst tensor is not initialized.
00 of size 4096 next 210
2023-12-19 11:40:36.751268: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1095] Free  at 7fbf3a06df00 of size 134656 next 281
2023-12-19 11:40:36.751272: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1095] InUse at 7fbf3a08ed00 of size 1792 next 284
2023-12-19 11:40:36.751275: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1095] InUse at 7fbf3a08f400 of size 1792 next 512
2023-12-19 11:40:36.751279: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1095] InUse at 7fbf3a08fb00 of size 7680 next 208
2023-12-19 11:40:36.751283: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1095] InUse at 7fbf3a091900 of size 160000 next 91
2023-12-19 11:40:36.751287: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1095] InUse at 7fbf3a0b8a00 of size 193792 next 47
2023-12-19 11:40:36.751290: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1095] InUse at 7fbf3a0e7f00 of size 256 next 96
2023-12-19 11:40:36.751294: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1095] InUse at 7fbf3a0e8000 of size 256 next 164
2023-12-19 11:40:36.751298: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1095] InUse at 7fbf3a0e8100 of size 256 next 290
2023-12-19 11:40:36.751301: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1095] InUse at 7fbf3a0e8200 of size 768 next 333
2023-12-19 11:40:36.751306: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1095] InUse at 7fbf3a0e8500 of size 512 next 54
2023-12-19 11:40:36.751309: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1095] InUse at 7fbf3a0e8700 of size 1792 next 302
2023-12-19 11:40:36.751313: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1095] InUse at 7fbf3a0e8e00 of size 512 next 539
2023-12-19 11:40:36.751317: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1095] InUse at 7fbf3a0e9000 of size 256 next 443
2023-12-19 11:40:36.751320: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1095] InUse at 7fbf3a0e9100 of size 256 next 452
2023-12-19 11:40:36.751324: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1095] InUse at 7fbf3a0e9200 of size 256 next 421
2023-12-19 11:40:36.751327: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1095] InUse at 7fbf3a0e9300 of size 256 next 194
2023-12-19 11:40:36.751331: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1095] InUse at 7fbf3a0e9400 of size 256 next 174
2023-12-19 11:40:36.751335: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1095] InUse at 7fbf3a0e9500 of size 256 next 156
2023-12-19 11:40:36.751338: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1095] InUse at 7fbf3a0e9600 of size 256 next 622
2023-12-19 11:40:36.751342: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1095] InUse at 7fbf3a0e9700 of size 256 next 20595
2023-12-19 11:40:36.751345: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1095] InUse at 7fbf3a0e9800 of size 256 next 88
2023-12-19 11:40:36.751349: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1095] InUse at 7fbf3a0e9900 of size 6400 next 49
2023-12-19 11:40:36.751353: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1095] InUse at 7fbf3a0eb200 of size 160000 next 17243
2023-12-19 11:40:36.751357: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1095] InUse at 7fbf3a112300 of size 160000 next 98
2023-12-19 11:40:36.751360: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1095] InUse at 7fbf3a139400 of size 96000 next 20638
2023-12-19 11:40:36.751364: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1095] InUse at 7fbf3a150b00 of size 160000 next 12966
2023-12-19 11:40:36.751368: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1095] InUse at 7fbf3a177c00 of size 96000 next 20589
2023-12-19 11:40:36.751372: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1095] InUse at 7fbf3a18f300 of size 462080 next 18446744073709551615
2023-12-19 11:40:36.751375: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1100]      Summary of in-use Chunks by size: 
2023-12-19 11:40:36.751381: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1103] 46 Chunks of size 256 totalling 11.5KiB
2023-12-19 11:40:36.751385: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1103] 2 Chunks of size 512 totalling 1.0KiB
2023-12-19 11:40:36.751389: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1103] 1 Chunks of size 768 totalling 768B
2023-12-19 11:40:36.751393: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1103] 2 Chunks of size 1280 totalling 2.5KiB
2023-12-19 11:40:36.751398: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1103] 5 Chunks of size 1792 totalling 8.8KiB
2023-12-19 11:40:36.751402: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1103] 3 Chunks of size 2048 totalling 6.0KiB
2023-12-19 11:40:36.751406: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1103] 1 Chunks of size 2816 totalling 2.8KiB
2023-12-19 11:40:36.751410: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1103] 4 Chunks of size 4096 totalling 16.0KiB
2023-12-19 11:40:36.751414: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1103] 1 Chunks of size 6400 totalling 6.2KiB
2023-12-19 11:40:36.751418: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1103] 1 Chunks of size 7680 totalling 7.5KiB
2023-12-19 11:40:36.751423: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1103] 2 Chunks of size 96000 totalling 187.5KiB
2023-12-19 11:40:36.751427: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1103] 5 Chunks of size 160000 totalling 781.2KiB
2023-12-19 11:40:36.751431: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1103] 1 Chunks of size 193792 totalling 189.2KiB
2023-12-19 11:40:36.751436: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1103] 2 Chunks of size 224000 totalling 437.5KiB
2023-12-19 11:40:36.751440: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1103] 1 Chunks of size 250112 totalling 244.2KiB
2023-12-19 11:40:36.751445: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1103] 2 Chunks of size 400128 totalling 781.5KiB
2023-12-19 11:40:36.751449: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1103] 1 Chunks of size 462080 totalling 451.2KiB
2023-12-19 11:40:36.751453: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1103] 4 Chunks of size 560128 totalling 2.14MiB
2023-12-19 11:40:36.751457: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1103] 3 Chunks of size 1000192 totalling 2.86MiB
2023-12-19 11:40:36.751461: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1103] 1 Chunks of size 1190144 totalling 1.13MiB
2023-12-19 11:40:36.751465: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1103] 1 Chunks of size 7060224 totalling 6.73MiB
2023-12-19 11:40:36.751470: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1103] 1 Chunks of size 7632206592 totalling 7.11GiB
2023-12-19 11:40:36.751474: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1103] 1 Chunks of size 7632816896 totalling 7.11GiB
2023-12-19 11:40:36.751478: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1107] Sum Total of in-use chunks: 14.23GiB
2023-12-19 11:40:36.751482: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1109] Total bytes in pool: 21591359488 memory_limit_: 21591359488 available bytes: 0 curr_region_allocation_bytes_: 34359738368
2023-12-19 11:40:36.751490: I tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:1114] Stats: 
Limit:                     21591359488
InUse:                     15281725696
MaxInUse:                  15307991808
NumAllocs:                  1808070556
MaxAllocSize:               7632816896
Reserved:                            0
PeakReserved:                        0
LargestFreeBlock:                    0

2023-12-19 11:40:36.751499: W tensorflow/tsl/framework/bfc_allocator.cc:497] ************************************____*************************************_________________*____*
```

I am using an AWS EC2 g5.12xlarge_4GPUx24GB=96 GB GPU Memory